# Is there a way to read logo images from different news sources with an standard approach?

Tags: python, rss, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm currently developing a news republishing web site which reads news from rss feeds.  the problem is when I try to get the news logo images from different news agencies that differs in each web site. currently I'm using about 200 IF commands for 200 webs.
This is my code using python:

```
try:
    img = soup.body.find('div', {'class': 'image-wrap'}).img.attrs['src']
    Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(str(img)).read()))
except:
    try:
        img = soup.body.find('div', {'id': 'post-body'}).a.attrs['href']
        Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(str(img)).read()))
    except:
        try:
            img = soup.body.find('div', {'class': 'image'}).img.attrs['src']
        except:
            img = soup.head.find('meta', {'property': 'og:image'}).attrs['content']
            if "breakingnews5.jpg" in img:
                img = ""
```

Is it possible to store an information about each web in the database and use that to extract image?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fixed list of about 200 services I would suggest building a dictionary or the images with so separate code that lets you manually see the feed and select the image that is the logo and saves it to a logos directory with a fixed naming convention.

Comment: How the dictionary is formatted? The format of each news agency is different. What should I do?

Comment: Rather than a huge if statement either come up with a fingerprint of how each feed formats its logo and store the fingerprints in a python dictionary or don't try and display the logo from the feed have your own captured logos for each feed.